# AWS Elasticache Vs API Gateway Cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elasticache

I am new to Serverless architecture using AWS Lambda and still trying to figure out how some of the pieces fit together. I have converted my website from EC2 (React client, and node API) to a serverless architecture. The React Client is now using s3 static web hosting and the API has been converted over to use AWS Lambda and API Gateway.

In my previous implementation I was using redis as a cache for caching responses from other third party API's.

API Gateway has the option to enable a cache, but I have also looked into Elasticache as an option. They are both comparable in price with API Gateway cache being slightly costlier.

The one issue I have run into when trying to use Elasticache is that it needs to be running in a VPC and I can no longer call out to my third party API's.

I am wondering if there is any benefit to using one over the other? Right now the main purpose of my cache is to reduce requests to the API but that may change over time. Would it make sense to have a Lambda dedicated to checking Elasticache first to see if there is a value stored and if not triggering another Lambda to retrieve the information from the API or is this even possible. Or for my use case would API Gateway cache be the better option?

Or possibly a completely different solution all together. Its a bit of a shame that mainly everything else will qualify for the free tier but having some sort of cache will add around $15 a month.

I am still very new to this kind of setup so any kind of help or direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**I am wondering if there is any benefit to using one over the other?**

Apigateway internally uses Elasticache to support caching so functionally they both behave in same way. Advantage of using api gateway caching is that ApiGateway checks chache before invoking backend lambda, thus you save cost of lambda invocation for response which are served by cache.

Another difference will be that when you use api gateway cache , cache lookup time will not be counted towards  "29s integration timeout" limit for cache miss cases.

**Right now the main purpose of my cache is to reduce requests to the API but that may change over time.**

I will suggest to make your decision about cache based on current use case. You might use completely new cache or different solution for other caching requirement.

**Would it make sense to have a Lambda dedicated to checking Elasticache first to see if there is a value stored and if not triggering another Lambda to retrieve the information from the API or is this even possible. Or for my use case would API Gateway cache be the better option?**

In general, I will not suggest to have additional lambda just for checking cache value ( just to avoid latency and aggravate lambda's cold start problem ). Either way, as mentioned above this way you will end up paying for lambda invokation even for requests which are being served by cache. If you use api gateway cache , cached requests will not even reach lambda.

Comment: "Apigateway internally uses Elasticache to support caching so functionally they both behave in same way" - Could you please point me to an AWS reference where this is stated? Admittedly this is the likely scenario, however I haven't come across any API gateway documentation that mentions this. Thanks

Comment: I second this answer. Better to use API Gateway for caching over Elasticache for cost-saving. The latter adds up the complexity and requires provisioning of additional resources. But beware of API Gateway caching limitations

Comment: @numX yes it is not publicly documented information but I can confirm this as a developer in API gateway team.